# R data.table. If column x then row count, else sum

Tags: r, data.table, conditional-statements, apply, lapply

Afternoon

Let's say I have this table:

```
df <- data.table(date = rep(c(1,2), each = 2)
                 , user = rep(c(1,2), 2)
                 , turnover = 2:5
                 , profit = 1:4
                 ); df

date user turnover profit
 1    1        2      1
 1    2        3      2
 2    1        4      3
 2    2        5      4
```

if I wanted to sum multiple columns I would:

```
# metrics
x <- c('user', 'turnover', 'profit')

# apply
df[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(x)), .SDcols=x, by=date]
```

which gives:

```
date user turnover profit
 1    3        5      3
 2    3        9      7
```

However, notice summing users does not make sense, instead I would like a row count for column "user" i.e.

```
date user turnover profit
 1    2        5      3
 2    2        9      7
```

Assume I didn't want to do a dummy column of 1s and sum that, instead I insisted on using `apply` ***and*** `data.table`. How would I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one possibility. You could combine the `c` and `lapply` functions together as follows (note that `.N` is the row count for each group):

```
df[, c(.(user=.N), lapply(.SD, sum)), by=date, .SDcols=c("turnover", "profit")]

#    date user turnover profit
# 1:    1    2        5      3
# 2:    2    2        9      7
```

Comment: While this works (thank you), it would not be efficient if I had a number of columns to do another operation on. Is there a method which would deal with this?

Comment: It really depends on what you would like to do. Remember that a list in `j` gets turned into columns (each element of the list becomes a column) and several lists can be turned into a single list using `c` function. So you can combine several other operations to what I did using this trick. For instance: `df[, c(.(user=.N), lapply(.SD, sum), lapply(.SD, mean)), ...]`.  Here I compute the row count, sum, and mean together. You can add other operations. *continue (see next comment)*

Comment: Whether what you do is efficient or not is operation-specific. Check the optimization level *'>= 1'*  (item 3) at [datatable.optimize: Optimisations in data.table](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.14.0/topics/datatable.optimize).
So even after combining several operations using this technique, you could still benefit from internal optimizations for expressions with similar structure. I could help you in a better way if I know exactly what other operations you would like to do.

Comment: Hi, Christian. You did answer my Q. From @akrun 's benchmarking yours is the 2nd fastest only behind `collapse`, a package I'm new to.
I take back what I said about inefficiency. Although I did not mean about run time (I meant from a syntax point of view), I thought what if I had 10 columns to count na of but also grouped by date?
How would one code that? I'm still parsing through all suggestions. Thank you all

Answer (score 3):

Here are approaches to apply *different* functions to *different* columns of a [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) as requested by the OP in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68304045/r-data-table-if-column-x-then-row-count-else-sum#comment120718709_68304448).

#### 1. Using `c()` and separate calls to `.SD` and `.SDcols`

```
df[, c(.SD[, lapply(.SD, length), .SDcols = c("user")], 
       .SD[, lapply(.SD, sum), .SDcols = c("turnover", "profit")]), by = date]
```

> ```
>    date user turnover profit
> 1:    1    2        5      3
> 2:    2    2        9      7
> ```

This is not quite elegant, pretty wordy, and presumably has performance penalties but does the job - and it keeps the column names.

#### 2. Using `purrr::map2()`

```
df[, purrr::map2(list(length, sum, sum), .SD, \(fn, args) purrr::exec(fn, args)), by = date]
```

> ```
>    date V1 V2 V3
> 1:    1  2  5  3
> 2:    2  2  9  7
> ```

This is less wordy but the column names are lost, unfortunately.

#### 3. Using `purrr::map2()` and naming the columns appropriately

```
df[, {
  fct <- c("length", "sum", "sum")
  res <- setDT(purrr::map2(fct, .SD, \(fn, args) purrr::exec(fn, args)))
  setnames(res, paste(names(.SD), fct, sep = "_"))
}, by = date]
```

> ```
>    date user_length turnover_sum profit_sum
> 1:    1           2            5          3
> 2:    2           2            9          7
> ```

This will work also if columns are selected using `.SDcols`:

```
df[, {
  fct <- c("length", "mean")
  res <- setDT(purrr::map2(fct, .SD, \(fn, args) purrr::exec(fn, args)))
  setnames(res, paste(names(.SD), fct, sep = "_"))
}, .SDcols = 2:3, by = date]
```

> ```
>    date user_length turnover_mean
> 1:    1           2           2.5
> 2:    2           2           4.5
> ```

#### 4. Using `purrr::map2()` and flexible column naming

If `fct` is a named vector and a function has been named, the given name will be used for the respective column. Otherwise, the created name will be used:

```
df[, {
  fct <- c(N = "length", "mean")
  res <- setDT(purrr::map2(fct, .SD, \(fn, args) purrr::exec(fn, args)))
  given_names <- names(fct)
  created_names <- paste(names(.SD), fct, sep = "_")
  setnames(res, 
           if (is.null(given_names)) 
             created_names 
           else 
             fifelse(given_names == "", created_names, given_names))
}, .SDcols = 2:3, by = date]
```

> ```
>    date N turnover_mean
> 1:    1 2           2.5
> 2:    2 2           4.5
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` with `across`, which is more flexible in doing these operations

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     group_by(date) %>%
     summarise(user = n(), across(c(turnover, profit), sum))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
   date  user turnover profit
  <dbl> <int>    <int>  <int>
1     1     2        5      3
2     2     2        9      7
```

---

Or another option in `collapse` from the same team that build `data.table` for the sole purpose of more efficiency.

```
library(collapse)
collap(df, ~ date, custom = list(fsum = c("turnover", "profit"), 
           fNobs = "turnover"))
   date fsum.turnover fNobs.turnover fsum.profit
1:    1             5              2           3
2:    2             9              2           7
```

---

#### Benchmarks

Tested on a bigger dataset

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(collapse)
library(purrr)

# input data
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data.table(date = rep(1:1e6, each = 20),
                  user = rep(1:1e6, 20),
                  turnover = rnorm(1e6 * 20),
                  profit = rnorm(1e6 * 20))

# benchmarks
# - B. Christian Kamgang
system.time({
  df1[, c(.(user=.N), lapply(.SD, sum)), by=date, .SDcols=c("turnover", "profit")]
  
})
#user  system elapsed 
#0.558   0.110   0.670 

# - Uwe
#   - first
system.time({
  df1[, c(.SD[, lapply(.SD, length), .SDcols = c("user")], 
          .SD[, lapply(.SD, sum), .SDcols = c("turnover", "profit")]), by = date]
  
})
#Timing stopped at: 245.9 3.336 249.4  0 stopped as it was taking time
#   - second
system.time({
  df1[, purrr::map2(list(length, sum, sum), .SD, \(fn, args) purrr::exec(fn, args)), by = date]
  
  
})
#user  system elapsed 
#37.816   0.138  38.016 
#   - third
system.time({
  
  df1[, {
    fct <- c("length", "sum", "sum")
    res <- setDT(purrr::map2(fct, .SD, \(fn, args) purrr::exec(fn, args)))
    setnames(res, paste(names(.SD), fct, sep = "_"))
  }, by = date]
  
  
})
#user  system elapsed 
#134.966   1.530 136.620 
#  - fourth
system.time({
    df1[, {
      fct <- c("length", "mean")
      res <- setDT(purrr::map2(fct, .SD, \(fn, args) purrr::exec(fn, args)))
      setnames(res, paste(names(.SD), fct, sep = "_"))
    }, .SDcols = 2:3, by = date]
})
#user  system elapsed 
#128.036   1.426 129.610 


#   - fifth
system.time({
    df1[, {
      fct <- c(N = "length", "mean")
      res <- setDT(purrr::map2(fct, .SD, \(fn, args) purrr::exec(fn, args)))
      given_names <- names(fct)
      created_names <- paste(names(.SD), fct, sep = "_")
      setnames(res, 
               if (is.null(given_names)) 
                 created_names 
               else 
                 fifelse(given_names == "", created_names, given_names))
    }, .SDcols = 2:3, by = date]
  
})
#user  system elapsed 
#131.960   1.552 133.595
```

-Timings of solutions from this post

```
# - akrun
#    - first
system.time({
  df1 %>%
    group_by(date) %>%
    summarise(user = n(), across(c(turnover, profit), sum))
})
#user  system elapsed 
#15.920   0.372  16.322 
#   - second
system.time({
  collap(df1, ~ date, custom = list(fsum = c("turnover", "profit"), 
                                   fNobs = "turnover"))
})

#user  system elapsed 
#0.311   0.005   0.316
```

Comment: My apologies for the late reply. Much appreciated for the benchmarking, speed is always important to me, hence, my focus on `data.table`. I shall look into `collapse`